# How to use NewMessage event of telethon on google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, telegram, telethon

I have this code and I want to run it on google colab. It works great on my PC but on colab I always get errors like these:

> SyntaxError: 'async with' outside async function

or

> RuntimeError: You must use "async with" if the event loop is running (i.e. you are inside an "async def")

sometimes it does not wait for getting new messages and finish after one running.

```
import json
import time
import telethon as tlt
import asyncio
from telethon import events,TelegramClient

chat_name = "sample"


telegram_session="sample_1"
api_id = "0000000"
api_hash = ""

client = TelegramClient(None , api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chat_name))
async def handler(event):
    get_message = event.message.to_dict()
    get_message['date'] = get_message['date'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    message_json = json.dumps(get_message)
    print(message_json)
      
      
async with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `async with` inside of `async def`:

```py
...

async def main():
    async with client:
        await client.run_until_disconnected()

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: I did this but I got this runtime error: RuntimeError: This event loop is already running. What should I do? @Lonami

Comment: The code you posted does not run the loop anywhere else, so I can't really point where the mistake is...